# Using a variable in a conditional sentence

Tags: spss

I want to save a value in a variable and then use it in a conditional sentence. To clarify this I'll give you a simpler example: Imagine that I have a database with the kind of animal(dogs and cats),their age(1 or 2) and their weight. I want to do the following conditional:

```
IF( animal=dog & age=1 & weight>= percentile75 ) Wdogs=1.
EXECUTE.
IF( animal=dog & age=1 & weight<percentile75) Wdogs=0.
EXECUTE
```

I want to calculate percentile75 automatically and save in a variable so I can use the code in any database I have. Also I want to rewrite the variables if I change the database and execute the code. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use RANK in order to divide the weights into n groups. The command creates a new rank variable which you can then use in your conditionals. 
For the ranking to be done separately in each relevant sub-group, use the BY sub-command. 
In your example, each animal/weight subgroup will be ranked separately into weight quartiles, and the subsequent command will use the new variable:

```
RANK VARIABLES=weight (A) BY animal weight/NTILES(4).
IF(animal=dog & age=1 & Nweight=4) Wdogs=1.
IF(animal=dog & age=1 & Nweight<=3) Wdogs=0.
EXECUTE.
```

You can save a line of syntax by using (instead of the two if commands):

```
IF(animal=dog & age=1) Wdogs=(Nweight=4).
```

Comment: Thank you mate. I forgot to say that I need the percentile of the each subgroup. For example, I need the percentile of the weight for dogs and age=1. Can I do it with your code?

Comment: my code already does that - see the BY sub-command. I added an edit to clarify that.

Comment: Awesome mate. I'll try to do with your code.Thank you very much

Comment: Hello mate. I've tested your code and I have a problem. I need to do that with percentiles 75 , 85 and 90. I've done with percentile 90 and it works well. After that I've done with percentile 85(I've calculated ntiles(100) ) but it doesn't work. It seems that to do the conditional takes the first rank althought it creates the second rank. Do I explain well?Thanks!

Comment: If you've calculated a few ranks based on the same original variable, the rank variables that SPSS creates get different names. make sure your syntax calls the right variable names in the right places. Also I recommend you look up the RANK command, and check what you want to do in the situation of ties (you should have some if you're using ntiles(100).

Comment: I suggest you mark this question as answered and start another question for the new problem (include your syntax with some sample data).

Answer (score 1):

First thing mate is lose those EXECUTE commands (They are unnecessary and betray you as a noob point and clicker with default options).  From other posts I discern you need to do that with multiple variables.  Simplify your life by boning up on VARSTOCASES, maintain the current RANK with BY and put a f'ing Shrimp (or a PRAWN) on the Barbie Queue.