# Save a value into a variable and then use it

Tags: spss

I need to calculate the percentile 85 and then save in a variable because I want to use it in many condition sentences like:

```
IF(variable>percentile85) a=0.
IF(variable2>percentile85) b=0.
IF(variable3>percentile85) c=0.
```

Is there a way to save a value into a variable and then use it?

Comment: Can you be more specific? What language are you programming this in? Of you should be able to save it in a variable what's the problem?

Comment: @MindRoller I'm programming in SPSS and I don't know how to save a value into a variable and then use it in a condition sentence

Comment: Well I've never used it so I will not be able to help, however something like defining and initializing variable should be EASY so you should look up some tutorials on the net I guess.

Comment: @MindRoller I've done it before I posted here but I didn't find out how to do it.

Comment: I have a blog post showing [how to do this](https://andrewpwheeler.wordpress.com/2015/04/13/extracting-items-from-spss-tables-using-python/). It is something that is somewhat annoying in SPSS.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37145579/using-a-variable-in-a-conditional-sentence/37146853?noredirect=1#comment61843770_37146853

Comment: Is this question solved?

Answer (score 1):

use RANK command with Ntiles, then use the new variable created:

```
RANK VARIABLES=YourVar(A) /NTILES(100).
IF(NYourVar>=85) a=0.
EXECUTE.
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that you can actually use Python in SPSS.  The downloadable Programming and Data Management book has many examples.  The SPSSINC TRANS extension command makes it particularly easy to do data transformations using Python code.